# Yii2 active record query returns the variables declared instead of the table attributes

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Why is it that when I retrieve a record from model, it returns the variable that I declared instead of the fields in the table.

This is my controller function

```
public function actionGetsp()
    {
      //$sp_id=$_POST['sp_id'];
      $model = TblSubProject::find()->select('sp_title, brgy_code')->all();
      return json_encode($model);
    }
```

and here is a part of my model.

```
class TblSubProject extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public $province;
    public $region;
    public $city_code;


    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'tbl_sub_project';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['city_code','brgy_code', 'sp_id', 'sp_title', 'sp_grant', 'lcc', 'modality'], 'required'],
            [['sp_id'], 'integer'],
            [['sp_grant', 'lcc'], 'number'],
            [['brgy_code'], 'string', 'max' => 9],
            [['sp_title'], 'string', 'max' => 500],
            [['modality'], 'string', 'max' => 50],
            [['sp_id'], 'unique']
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'brgy_code' => 'Brgy Code',
            'sp_id' => 'Sp ID',
            'sp_title' => 'Sp Title',
            'sp_grant' => 'Sp Grant',
            'lcc' => 'Lcc',
            'modality' => 'Modality',
            'city_code' => 'City / Municipality',
            'brgy_code' => 'Barangay',
            'brgyCode.cityCode.province.prov_name' => 'Province',
            'brgyCode.cityCode.city_name' => 'City / Municipality',
            'brgyCode.brgy_name' => 'Barangay',
        ];
    }
}
```

And here is sample output..

As you can say, it returns the province, region, and the city_code which is not an attribute in the table but just a declared variable. I want to retrieve like the si_title.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's a normal Yii ActiveRecord behaviour - it replaces table attributes with declared ones. You don't have do declare them: all table fields are already available as $model->$field.

Comment: actually im calling the action through ajax.. When I do `$model->$field.` it says 'Trying to get property of non-object'